# how to invoke and change the value of a component on handleSubmit in react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am coding with react. I  created a Form and on submit I want to send the value of the input field as parameter of another react component, here is "cypher_query" of   . Here is my code, it's not working, I don't know where I did mistake. Please help

```js
const AppGraph = () => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = (evt) =>  {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form  id="myForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <div className="App" style={{ fontFamily: "Quicksand" }}>
          <label htmlFor="CommentsOrAdditionalInformation">enter your query</label>
          <input 
            name = "requete"
            type="text"
            id="CommentsOrAdditionalInformation"
            value = {query}
            onChange={e => setQuery(e.target.value)}
          >
          </input>
          <input type = "submit" value="Submit" className="btn_submit" alt = "submit Checkout"/>
        </div>
      <p>{query}</p>   
      </form>
      {<ResponsiveNeoGraph
        containerId={"id0"}
        neo4jUri={NEO4J_URI}
        neo4jUser={NEO4J_USER}
        neo4jPassword={NEO4J_PASSWORD}
        cypher_query={query}  
      />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AppGraph;
```

Comment: what is the problem? the code looks OK

Comment: When I submit the form, the property cypher_query of the  component ResponsiveNeoGraph don't change

Comment: the property `cypher_query` is changed when you type in the input element, because it has `onChange`.

Comment: I found my mistakes, it was in the ResponsiveNeoGraph code, thanks  for your help 